# Powershell: Extract all file names from a directory and input them into a textbox

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2022

I have a directory of `pdf` files all named differently for example

SOR001.pdf
SOR002.pdf
SOR003.pdf

is it possible to extract just the `Basename` and input that information to a `textbox` in visual studio. the format i am looking for would be like this `(SOR001,SOR002,SOR003)`

Comment: In Visual Studio? Why not use the underlying .NET API's directly if you're developing a GUI app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a string like `(SOR001,SOR002,SOR003)`:

```bash
'({0})' -f ((Get-ChildItem *.pdf).BaseName -join ',')
```

To get a string like `('SOR001','SOR002','SOR003')`:

```bash
'({0})' -f ((Get-ChildItem *.pdf).BaseName.ForEach({ "'$_'" }) -join ',')
```

See also:

- `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)
- `-join`, the [string joining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join)
- [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration)
- The [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach)